# How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?

Tags: support, beta-sites, community-promotion-ads

All the launched sites get Community Promotion Ads meta posts posted every year by a SE mod.

Previously, I thought that beta sites simply weren't allowed them. However, [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) is still in beta, and they had community promotions meta posts in [2014](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/761/community-ads-on-the-network-2014-edition) and [2013](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/community-promotion-ads-on-the-se-network) (I guess they haven't made one for 2015 yet).

So what happens? Do you just have to ask for one? Can the moderators of that site just create one as they like? Can *anyone* on that site just create one as they like?

Comment: Just to be clear, the Anime & Manga *community* made those posts. As far as I can tell, they were never actually hooked up to the ad engine since that takes a developer to set up for a particular thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you should start a discussion on the site's Meta to ask the community if they want/need community promotion ads on their site. If the response is overwhelmingly positive, then Stack Exchange will set up the necessary systems to make it happen on your site. Most beta sites, though, don't have a community large or interested enough for these ads to be worthwhile or useful.

Anime & Manga does **not** have community promotion ads visible on *their site*. The Meta discussions created there were by the community for the purposes of **generating advertisements to place on *other* sites** to advertise the Anime & Managa site itself. Any member of the community can start a discussion like this, and there's no real reason to start a new one every year. If you have new ideas for ads to use across the network, just post a new answer with the image you want to be used.

Comment: Huh. So it can actually happen, then?

Comment: There's no rule that strictly prohibits a beta site from having community ads (and [the original blog about it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) states "all the public Stack Exchange sites"). It's just not something a beta site would normally be focusing on.

Comment: There's no *technical* restriction, but in practice a site would need an extremely pressing+unusual need for such ads in order for us to enable them on a beta site - AFAIK, we've only done this once or twice, and only temporarily. @starsplusplus

Answer (score 3):

Your classical community ads are ads displayed on graduated SE sites that advertise something useful to that community *on* that particular site, e.g., a proof database on Math or a font repository on Graphics Design.

Those posts on Anime & Manga aren’t about advertising something useful to this community (e.g., a manga database) on Anime & Manga but about advertising Anime & Manga itself on *other* sites using the aforementioned community ads.

I cannot find a current example for Anime & Manga, but [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5328/20840) is one for Movies & TV on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that! They had the red [community-ads] tag and repeated all the gumph about the formatting, so I didn't notice that really it was just a normal meta discussion post that was talking about making community ads on *other* sites!