# When does a site get Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

What are the requirements for a site to get *Community Promotion Ads*? Does it have to explicitly request them somehow or does it have to fullfill any additional constraints apart from graduation? Or is it simply a matter of waiting and seeing? In that case, is there some rough standard estimate of the expected timeframe?

I am specifically asking because [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) graduated about 66 days ago and there are no signs of a dedicated Community Promotion Ad post, so maybe there is another requirement we're missing. I already asked this question [over there](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1695/49), but since it didn't seem to get much attention by the actual responsible powers, I'll try here.

Comment: Similar: [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248214/191655)

Comment: @kenorb Ah, thanks. If those rules apply for full sites, too, then maybe I should first have asked on [meta.movies.se] if we want those at all. Though, I assumed that would be solved implicitly by just noone posting/voting an ad if they're not needed/wanted.

Comment: I think so, you should create a new meta post there similar as I've created [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1436/385). However I had different case, because the site is still beta and so it's [not likely to have ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites/248216#comment816265_248216) created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As none of the higher powers did so yet, I will answer this here based on what I got told:

It seems there is nothing special that has to be done by the community and the Community Promotion Ads should more or less coincide with graduation. In the example site employed by the question this was apparently just forgotten but [has since been corrected](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1745/49).